# How do I specify access to a hidden protected base class member?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, migration

I'm migrating code like this from MS VS6 to VS2010:

```
class A
{
protected:
    typedef void (A::*X_t)(int x);
    virtual void CallX(X_t x) {}
    virtual void X() {}
    virtual void X(int x) {}
};

class B: public A
{
protected:
    virtual void X()
    {
        this->CallX(&A::X);
    }    
};
```

This gets compiled in MS VS6 but in VS2010 it fails on

```
error C2248: 'A::X' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'
```

Is there any way out of this error?

Comment: Not sure it's much help to you, but `g++` doesn't complain, `clang++` does give this error "x.cpp:17:25: error: 'X' is a protected member of 'A'".

Comment: The problem is that `B` has access to members of its base class `A`, but not members of any other `A` (like an `A` base class of `C`). Don't know which category `&A::X` belongs to here. Would an `&this->A::X` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the standard, 11.4/1, to be honest, the language confuses me.  But the example is fairly clear:

```
class B {
protected:
    int i;
    static int j;
};

class D1 : public B {
};

class D2 : public B {
    friend void fr(B*,D1*,D2*);
    void mem(B*,D1*);
};

... irrelevant stuff snipped

void D2::mem(B* pb, D1* p1) {
    ...
    int B::* pmi_B = &B::i; // ill-formed  *****this*****
    int B::* pmi_B2 = &D2::i; // OK
    ...
}
```

The text [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr129.htm), while not directly from the standard, is more clear.

> If you reference a protected nonstatic member x of a base class A in a
>   friend or a member function of a derived class B, you must access x
>   through a pointer to, reference to, or object of a class derived from
>   A. However, if you are accessing x to create a pointer to member, you
>   must qualify x with a nested name specifier that names the derived
>   class B.

So, if my understanding is correct here, Visual Studio is right to reject this.

To fix it, I'm not sure if this is correct, but it appears to fix the problem for me in VS2012:

```
 this->CallX(&B::A::X);
```

However, the same thing does not appear to work for clang.

Comment: call `this->CallX(&B::A::X);` in `B::X` is recursion call?

Comment: @billz: No, it can't be, because `CallX` expects a member function with a different signature.  But, as I say, I don't know if Visual Studio is right to accept that, or if clang is right to reject it.

Comment: +1 You are right, I made a mistake in my testing code, coz I replace function pointer with std::function.

Comment: I temporarily added method "void B::X(int x) { A::X(x); }" but this with double namespace helped. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just as a curiosity, I haven't found anywhere any documentation for the &B::A::X syntax. (I don't know, how it is called, otherwise i'd google that)